# The .filter() method returns the starting array or an empty array

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to filter an array of objects using the `.filter()` method and the returned array is either empty or the whole array I was trying to filter. It doesn't show any errors, warnings, or some type of message that indicates something went wrong, so I thought probably I miss something in my logic/knowledge.

**Here's the code that I'm trying out:**

```js
    this.subscription = this.dataService.tasks.subscribe((tasks: Task[]) => {
          this.tasks = tasks.filter((task: Task) => {
            return task.status === true;
          });
        });
```

The `dataService.tasks` is a `BehaviorSubject<Task[]>`.

**For the cases below it returns the whole array of tasks:**

```js
    return task.status;
    return task.status !== true;
    return task.status !== false;
    return task.status != true;
    return task.status != false;
```

**And for these it returns an empty array:**

```js
    return !task.status;
    return task.status === true;
    return task.status === false;
    return task.status == true;
    return task.status == false;
```

I have also checked the values of the array and it certainly has false and true values as expected.

Here's the complete project i'm working on:
https://github.com/panagiotisplytas/planner

**The problem occurs in those two files on the** `ngOnInit()` **method:**

```
    src/app/pages/home/home.page.ts
    src/app/pages/history/history.page.ts
```

> The capacitor plugin i use for the sqlite database doesn't currently work with `electron` or the `web` platforms only `ios` and `android`, so if you want to reproduce the issue you will need to build the app for `android` or `ios`.

Comment: You're code looks ok, I think there is something else going on. I would suggest that you need to provide a working example that illustrates the problem. It is then going to be easy enough to debug what's really happening.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I uploaded the complete project on github, and added the link to it if you want to check it out.

Comment: I've had a look through your code and the problem doesn't look like its in the filter method. I suspect that when you read the tasks for the database.service the status field isn't being populated with what you expect. I would put a console.log in DatabaseService.readTasks and inside the filter method on tasks.filter to see what the data is you are actually filtering on. As I say, my guess is that it isn't what you think it is. If you had unit tests you would probably have found the problem and diagnosed it by now.

Comment: After many hours, i wasn't able to find where exactly is the problem but as you suggested something was off with the values still no visible anywhere, but i think it has something to do with how the sqlite database and typesript handle booleans. A simple workaround that worked for me was to change the status from boolean to number (both in the database and in the objects) and i works excactly as expected.